# How do I fire onkeyup event after I lost focus?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I've made an onkeyup event, and once I click on another textbox anywhere, and then click again on the textbox that fires the onkeyup, it won't fire it.

It does work the first time I click the textbox, though.

My code:


HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <span id="spanAvailability"></span>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="checkUsernameUsage(this.value)" style="font-size: 20px; text-align:center; border-radius: 20px;" class="RegisterButton" ValidationGroup="registergroup" placeholder="What's your Email?"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />   
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var usernameCheckerTimer;
                 var spanAvailability = $get("spanAvailability");

                 function checkUsernameUsage(username) {
                     clearTimeout(usernameCheckerTimer);
                     if (username.length == 0)
                         spanAvailability.innerHTML = "";
                     else {
                         spanAvailability.innerHTML = "<span style='color: #ccc;'>checking...</span>";
                         usernameCheckerTimer = setTimeout("checkUsernameUsage('" + username + "');", 750);
                     }
                 }

                 function checkUsernameUsage(username) {
                     // initiate the ajax pagemethod call
                     // upon completion, the OnSucceded callback will be executed
                     PageMethods.IsUserAvailable(username, OnSucceeded);
                 }

                 // Callback function invoked on successful completion of the page method.
                 function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
                     if (methodName == "IsUserAvailable") {
                         if (result == true)
                             spanAvailability.innerHTML = "<span style='color: Red;'>Unavailable</span>";
                         else
                             spanAvailability.innerHTML = "<span style='color: DarkGreen;'>Available</span>";
                     }
                 }
    </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: remove the `AutoPostBack="true"`?

Comment: That worked. By the way, I've got another problem with that. It actually intermittently works. It may work one time I refresh the page, and it may not, kind of randomly. Any idea why?